# Mention Facebook Page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, koala

I am using Koala to post on my Facebook wall and I would like to mention a page. But the following doesn't work:

```
@graph.put_wall_post("This page rocks: @[1466840030227949]")
```

Any way to do this with Koala? And without Koala?

Comment: Tagging is not possible in simple posts made via API.

Comment: I found this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-actions/v2.0#pages Not sure if it is compatible with Koala. What do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is old, but this answer may help someone else who ends up here.

the syntax above is correct with Koala. To mention a Facebook Page you need to include @[page-id] in the message parameter.

To use Page Mentioning with any Facebook Page, your app need to have been granted the manage_pages and publish_actions permissions. Your app will also need approval for the [Page Mention feature](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#reference-MENTIONING).

There is a way to test this without being approved for the permission or feature but please check out [my related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35757306/how-to-mention-a-facebook-page-as-a-test-user-with-the-graph-api) and [the Facebook docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/page/feed#pubperms) for more information on how to do that.