# How to mention a Facebook Page as a test user with the Graph API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, koala-gem, mention

I understand that in order for me to mention a Facebook page before submitting it for approval I must be posting as a page I admin, tagging a page I admin and using an app I admin - otherwise, the tags are not applied.

The problem with this is that test users are not app admins. I know I can use my personal account since I'm an admin of the app, but I want to avoid creating actual Facebook accounts/Pages to test this functionality. I would like to know how/if it is possible to test page mentions using a test users account.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25999256/mention-facebook-page-in-page-api-post/35750824#35750824) is what made me realize that I was going about it in the wrong way, but still leaves me with the question I'm asking now. Thank you in advance!

Comment: add your update as answer and link to the bug report if possible

Comment: Thank you, I have done that now!

Answer (score 1):

## **UPDATE**

I reached out to Facebook and It is not possible to use test users for page mentions. The only way to test this functionality is with your personal account (or real FB accounts that admin your app).

[Facebook response](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/963789523706404/):

> Hi Peter,
>
> Thanks for reaching out. This is indeed expected behavior. You can only test this with pages you are an admin of and an app you are the developer of.
>
> As a test user can't be a developer on your app and also can't interact with real Facebook accounts you will have to test this with your personal account.
>
> Hope this helps.
>
> Thanks, Björn

Hope this helps someone in the future!

Comment: Hi @Peter Ortiz, i'm facing the same issue, can you help me please? I'm tryin to post an status as a FanPage (that i'm admin of), with an App that i'm admin too, and tagging another page that i'm admin, using v2.10 of Graph API. I missing somenthig related with my user, that is the admin of all pages and admins.. i think.. ? Should I use the admin user access token in some place? Thanks!